# Bluemix - Container Health Error

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud

The Liberty for Java Container build process is running for days. The exact message that I see under the Container Health section is:

```
Your container is building
```

Any help on creating container or deleting this hanging container is appreciated. Please see the attached [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJVfW.jpg) to view the container status that is referenced above.

Comment: Hi Sri. Can you provide some log file information to determine the issue? There could be a number of reasons why that message is being displayed. You can use the cf ic logs <container> command to view the logs.

Comment: Could you please run "ice ps -a" or "cf ic ps -a" and let me know if container is listed? Post output here if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it happens that a container is in '*Building*' state for too long and it usually means that there was an infrastructure problem. You can try to create a new container from the same image with *cf ic run* or *ice run*. Please consider that if you reached the maximum quota you could need to delete the stuck container or to release unbound IPs in order to create a new one. You can delete a container using:

> cf ic rm -f *[containerId]*

To get the container id you can run:

> cf ic ps -a

You can list all IPs (available or not) using:

> cf ic ip list -a

Then you can release an IP using:

> cf ic ip release [IPAddr]